# Why do I need to add NetworkCredential again?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

In visual studios I added a service reference (web reference). There I entred the URL to the web service (soap).
I needed to authenticate against it, and I did.

Now when I make a request to it I get "The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized".
I solve that by adding:

```
var service = new MyWebService();
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password", "domain");
```

And it works fine. But why do I need to enter it again? Is it possible to save the authentication information?

Comment: The credentials aren't going to be stored in the WSDL - that would be counter-productive.  You *can* save the authentication information in your app (the client) [but please don't do it in plain text in the config file!].

Comment: Ok, then its better to have it in my .cs file as it is now?

Comment: Yes, but be aware that if the credentials change you'll need to rebuild your application.  We have something like this at work, but we have a dedicated service that applications use to retrieve credentials at run time.  This allows us to update the database behind that credential service without rebuilding all our applications.

Comment: You could also encrypt the credentials in the config file.  Do a search on encrypting .net config file or similar strings.  We've done that as well for apps that live in our DMZ.